# How to select option value from select tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry guys, previously I didn't mention the my dropdown list is made with bootstrap. based on @rps suggestion I asked to my colleague(who is made template) he said it's made with bootstrap.

I am putting basic html dropdown code,so I think you guys can understand How bootstrap code will be.

html code:

```
<select name="primary" class="select-block" id="select_alert">
   <option "selected">Choose Alert T</option>                         
   <option value="T1">T1</option>
   <option value="T2">T2</option>
   <option value="T3">T3</option>
   <option value="T4">T4</option>
</select>
```

Initially i am getting the select menu in the following way.

[image]

for my conformation,I am finding the menu value in the following way.

```
i/p: document.getElementById('select_alert').value
o/p: "choose Alert T"
```

Now using javascript or jquery, I want to change select option in the follwoing way.For this I tried the below it's not working

[image]

```
       document.getElementById('select_alert').value="T1";
```

Again If I check the value of select menu,it should be "T1".

Thanks

Comment: your code should be working, There must be some other issue! where have you written `document.getElementById('select_alert').value="T1"` ? Might be helpful if you paste you entire code in the question

Comment: are you trying to get the value of the currently selected option? or change the select menu to a specific option?

Comment: @CoreyRothwell I am trying to change select menu to specific option.

Comment: @all I updated my question, I hope now you can understand what I am trying.

Comment: @rps I updated my question. can you check it and help me out.

Comment: @user2873816 Take a look at [***This***](http://jsfiddle.net/UUmHe/), your JavaScript code is correct, Just make sure that the script code is placed somewhere in the document where it is getting executed and not overridden.

Comment: @rps thanks for your suggestion.I am using bootstrap dropdown list.Actually template was given by one of my colleague. so I don't about this.On normal html dropdown list my javascript code working fine.It's not working on bootstrap element.

Comment: @user2873816 how about the jquery answers below? They work?

Comment: @rps The below answers are not working.

Comment: @user2873816, it is difficult to pinpoint the issue without seeing the entire code of your page, try removing `"selected"` from `<option "selected">Choose Alert T</option>` and also where are you writing the JS code to select the option in your page? in load function?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

// Get the value from a dropdown select

```
$( "#select_alert option:selected").val();

$( "#select_alert option:selected" ).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

My reading of the question is ambiguous, but if you're trying to *set* the value, or set the selected-option, to `T1`:

```
$('#select_alert option[value="T1"]').prop('selected',true);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7F8kQ/).

If you're trying to retrieve the value of the selected option:

```
$('#select_alert option:selected').val();
```

Comment: after running your first statement code I want to see "T1" on top of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Using **jQuery** you can just do this:

```
$('#select_alert').val('T1');
```

Demo : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3sV3a/)

Answer (score 0):

use as follows :

```
$('#select_alert').val('T1'); // in jquery
```

also your javascript code is correct, there must be some other error on the page.

Answer (score 0):

without jquery you can use

```
document.getElementById('select_alert').selectedIndex = 1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uzqZA/1/

if you want to find out the option index by given value try this

```
var sel = document.getElementById('select_alert'),
    selopt = sel.options,
    searchidx;

//alert(selopt[sel.selectedIndex].value);
//sel.selectedIndex = 1;
//alert(selopt[sel.selectedIndex].value);
//alert(sel.value)


// search for the index
searchidx = getoptidx(selopt, "T3");

if (searchidx !== false) {
    sel.selectedIndex = searchidx;
    alert(selopt[sel.selectedIndex].value);
} else {
    alert("index not found")
}

/**
 * returns the index of a value
 * @todo optimize search?
 */
function getoptidx(opts, searchterm) {
    for (var i in opts) {
        if (opts[i].text === searchterm) return i;
    }
    return false;
}
```

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzqZA/6/

Comment: I don't know index,I will get option value from somewhere,I just want to show that value on top of the menu like how I showed in my question.

Comment: fiddle kinda struggling now, i pasted the code into the answer, maybe this one will help

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way :

```
$('#select_alert').val("T3");
$("#select_alert").selectmenu();
$("#select_alert").selectmenu("refresh");
```